# xlsx to plist in Spanish - accented characters being lost

Tags: ios, ipad, plist

I have been using "Plist Converter" to get my data from csv files (excel spreadsheets saved as csv files) into plists up to now and have never had any issues with it.

However, I am currently working on an app where the data I need to convert is in Spanish.

The conversion obviously still works but I lose all of the accented characters during the process.  It looks like maybe some are just lost, some are changed to other accents/characters, and the majority are replaced with an upside down question mark that does not appear on the screen but I can see it in the source code.

Anyone help me get around this with plist converter, or recommend another utility?

iMac, Excel for mac, plist converter, xcode... that is what I'm using.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at libxls on SouceForge - it comes with a utility to take a .xls file and create a .csv one that you can further process using command line tools. But it has no support for .xlsx.

Comment: My mistake in the original question ... I am saving my xlsx files as csv files and converting those csv files.  The csv files seem OK when I look at them, they have all the correct characters at least.  It is only when I try using "Plist Converter" that I run into problems.  Maybe it has no support for extended character sets...

Comment: Any suggestions for a tool that will work?  I'm going to do another google anyway because I might have been looking for 'xlsx to plist', when I meant 'csv to plist'...

Comment: I don't know 'Plist Converter' but writing something yourself is pretty easy to do. There are open source csv ObjectiveC frameworks.